# How does the JUnit plugin in Eclipse get the list of test methods in my class?

Tags: spring, testing, junit

I am running my test in a Spring Boot application that contains several usual annotations:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = { "DEV" })
@TestConfiguration
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Application.class }, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public abstract class IntegrationTestBase {
..
}
```

and my other tests simply extend this class and I have a bunch of methods in there annotated with `@Test`. When I launch this I see that first Spring is booted (at this time the JUnit view in Eclipse does not show test methods yet) and when that process finishes my test methods appear there magically and the execution starts.

I am wondering what works under the hood that makes this work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not have a specific programming question

Comment: Not quite sure, but afaik, JUnit does absolutely nothing to find those classes, it just runs the classes that were given to it. It's the job of the surrounding application to give them to JUnit. This can be done, for example, by Eclipse or Maven, both of them simply look for appropriately called classes ("...Test", "Test...", "...IT", etc.). You can test that by simply invoking the `JUnitCore` class' main method with your test class as an argument.